# Flutter pagination loading the same data as in page one when scrolling

Tags: flutter

I'm building a list of news from an api that has next page results as in the image attached.
The api has only two pages with 10 list items each page.

Data is being passed to the widget. My problem is that when I scroll down the view, it loads the same 10 list items from page one.

This is the api I'm using [enter link description here](https://jabbolt.com/api/news)

[Rest API](https://jabbolt.com/api/news)

```
//newsModal.dart
class NewsNote {
  String banner_image;
  String title;
  String text;
  String sport;

  NewsNote(this.banner_image, this.title, this.text, this.sport);

  NewsNote.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    banner_image = json['banner_image'];
    title = json['title'];
    text = json['text'];
    sport = json['sport'];
  }

}
//page news
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:jabboltapp/models/newsModal.dart';

class JabNews extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JabNewsState createState() => _JabNewsState();
}

class _JabNewsState extends State<JabNews> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;

  String url = "https://jabbolt.com/api/news";

  List<NewsNote> _newsNotes = List<NewsNote>();

  Future<List<NewsNote>> fetchNewsNotes() async {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      var response = await http.get(url);

      var newsNotes = List<NewsNote>();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        url = jsonDecode(response.body)['next'];
        var newsNotesJson = json.decode(response.body)["results"];
        for (var newsNoteJson in newsNotesJson) {
          newsNotes.add(NewsNote.fromJson(newsNoteJson));
        }
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          _newsNotes.addAll(newsNotes);
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
      return newsNotes;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchNewsNotes().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _newsNotes.addAll(value);
      });
    });
    this.fetchNewsNotes();
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        fetchNewsNotes();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: isLoading ? 1.0 : 00,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index == _newsNotes.length) {
          return _buildProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text((_newsNotes[index].title)),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailPage(_newsNotes[index])));
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: _newsNotes.length,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: dGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "News",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: textGrey,
            fontFamily: 'bison',
            fontSize: 32.0,
            letterSpacing: 1.2,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: _buildList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to get a data from API by page, right now you are getting it all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the page number concatenation in the URL
https://jabbolt.com/api/news?page=2

Comment: Just do this? String url = "https://jabbolt.com/api/news?page=2"; but eventually that  it will be more than two pages.